# iPhone Safari - Prevent prev/next button events

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios7, ios6, html5-video

In iPhone Safari, when playing an HTML5 video, how can I prevent the previous/next buttons from functioning? YouTube's mobile site does this for their advertisements, so it's definitely possible.

From my research, I've found pressing the "next" button causes the `timeupdate`, `pause`, `seeking`, and `ended` events to fire, roughly in that order. Calling `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` in a listener on any of these seem to do nothing (I am not sure if this is correct behavior on iPhone; Apple's Safari dev guide does not provide much info on video events).

So, how can I do this? I tried listening to the `seeking` event, but that doesn't seem to *always* fire when next is pressed (I have no clue why). Also, even if I do listen on that event, the `ended` event is still fired immediately after, and I have not found a way to prevent this. `ended` seems to be the event that tells the player to close, which is NOT what I want to happen.

The ideal method IMO would be to listen on `timeupdate` for a large change, then set the video's `currentTime` prop to its previous value—this is incredibly reliable and works great. If the user presses the "next" button, `timeupdate` indeed fires right away; however, `ended` *also* fires, causing the video player to close, making my update to `currentTime` useless.

I know this is possible, but there is surprisingly little info on the web or SO. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hi,

did you find a solution?

Comment: @ElizaS yes, i solved this by storing the video's `currentTime` inside a `timeupdate` listener. then, inside an event listener on the `ended` event, if the last `currentTime` i stored does NOT equal the video's `duration` (this would be the case if the video played to completion), pause the video, set its `currentTime` to the value i stored, then play the video.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I made something similar will send it as an answer here

Comment: If one of you could share an answer with some code, that would be awesome.

Is there any way to respond to the "previous" button?

Comment: @sgroves How ur getting the ad duration, I've used the seek, seeked events for prevent user seek to the end of the ad. but I'm stuck on the next button issue. can u please post the code as answer. so that it would be helpful for other individuals as well those coming through. Thank you.

Comment: @ElizaS pl. anyone share the code as answer. :(